# Approximation of 1-exp(-mu*t) when mu*t is very small

Tags: algebra, approximation

I am working on some fairly simple linear attenuation and absorption calculations and from high school math I seem to remember that there is an approximation of:

1-exp(-mu*t)

When

mu*t << 1

Does this approximation exist? I thought it was a taylor series expansion but could not convince myself after looking through old math textbooks.

Any help or direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `mu*t`, or `mu*t - (mu*t)^2/2`. For better approximations, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

mu*t plus O((mu*t)^2)

To see why, try rewriting this as `f(u) = 1-exp(-u)`, and taking a [Taylor series](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/TaylorSeries.aspx) expansion at the point `u=0`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C++11, for example, it has this function as part of the standard library: [`expm1`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/expm1/).

In your case, you would call it as `-expm1(-mu*t)`.

Otherwise, you can derive the Maclaurin series for `expm1` easily from the Maclaurin series for `exp(x)` by simply dropping the first 1. One implementation is given below in `expm1_maclaurin`.

Comparing this with the built-in `expm1`:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

double expm1_maclaurin( double x )
{
    const double order = 10;
    double retval = 1.0;
    for( int i = order ; 1 < i ; --i ) retval = 1.0 + x*retval/i;
    return x*retval;
}

int main()
{
    cout.precision(numeric_limits<double>::digits10);
    for( int i = 0 ; i <= 32 ; ++i )
    {
        double x = i < 0 ? 1.0 * (1u<<-i) : i < 32 ? 1.0 / (1u<<i) : 0;
        cout << "x=" << x << ' '
             << expm1(x) << ' '
             << expm1_maclaurin(x) << ' '
             << ( expm1(x) == expm1_maclaurin(x) ) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
x=1 1.71828182845905 1.71828180114638 0
x=0.5 0.648721270700128 0.648721270687366 0
x=0.25 0.284025416687742 0.284025416687735 0
x=0.125 0.133148453066826 0.133148453066826 1
x=0.0625 0.0644944589178594 0.0644944589178594 1
x=0.03125 0.0317434074991027 0.0317434074991027 1
...
```

For all positive `x <= 1/8` the result is equal to full `double` precision of `expm1`.